# Not able to install Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

I used to have a dual boot with windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.After a few months of installation my system started crashing almost everyday.
Whenever I boot up I used to get warnings like:

Firmware Bug

IOAPIC[4] not in IVRS table

IOAPIC[5] not in IVRS table

Can't request region for resource

Assuming it was a mistake from my part during partitioning I decided to reinstall this time with only Ubuntu 20.10. It started installation and I gave the option to erase disk and install Ubuntu but it faced an internal error during installation which stopped the process although I think the disk was erased.
Now I'm not able to install as there seems to be no device listed in  installation type section although I can see my hard disk listed in my BIOS information.

My device is a lenovo IdeaPad 330 with ryzen 5 and vega 8 graphics

Comment: Which installation error did you encounter? [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1287570/edit) your question and mention it.

Comment: I'm not sure what the error was... All it showed was "Ubuntu 20.10 faced an internal error"

Comment: If it happens again, take a screenshot (with phone, if the computer's screenshot tool cannot be used that moment). The error message window may have an option to show more details.